# Key / Value store with type classes for formatting / parsing

Tags: scala

I'm currently working on a Scala HTTP library, [fetch](https://github.com/nrinaudo/fetch), mostly because I have yet to find one that suits all my needs.

As part of this library, I need a generic key / value store, which I intend to use both for request / response headers and URL query parameters. This store uses type classes for value parsing and formatting, which makes it both type-safe and convenient to use: ETags, for example, can be manipulated through an `ETag` class, but I do not need the key / value store to be aware that etags even exist.

This is what I have come up with:

```
trait ValueReader[S, T] {
  def read(value: S): Try[T]
}

trait ValueWriter[S, T] {
  def write(value: S): Option[T]
}

class KeyValueStore[T](val values: Map[String, T] = Map()) {
  def apply[S](name: String)(implicit reader: ValueReader[T, S]): S =
    reader.read(values(name)).get

  def getOpt[S](name: String)(implicit reader: ValueReader[T, S]): Option[S] = for {
    raw    <- values.get(name)
    parsed <- reader.read(raw).toOption
  } yield parsed

  def get[S](name: String)(implicit reader: ValueReader[T, S]): Option[Try[S]] = values.get(name) map reader.read

  def set[S](name: String, value: S)(implicit writer: ValueWriter[S, T]): KeyValueStore[T] =
    writer.write(value).fold(this)(set(name, _))

  def set(name: String, value: T): KeyValueStore[T] = new KeyValueStore(values + (name -> value))

  def setIfEmpty[S](name: String, value: S)(implicit writer: ValueWriter[S, T]): KeyValueStore[T] =
      if(contains(name)) this
      else               set(name, value)

  def remove(name: String): KeyValueStore[T] =
      if(contains(name)) new KeyValueStore[T](values - name)
      else               this

  def contains(name: String): Boolean = values.contains(name)
}
```

See [this class](https://github.com/nrinaudo/fetch/blob/9926e26693ff4da7150dabce44f9b8c858ac33a7/core/src/main/scala/com/nrinaudo/fetch/ValueFormat.scala) for sample implementations of readers and writers.

I'd be very happy for this code to be criticised and improvements to be suggested, especially in the following areas:

- variance: I will probably end up making this covariant in `T`. Is there any reason not to do so?
- I've included three "accessor" methods: `apply` (which throws), `getOpt` (safe but doesn't let the caller know what went wrong) and `get` (safe, granular, but heavier). Is there a standard pattern for this, or is what I'm doing considered acceptable / idiomatic?
- I'm pretty sure I'm not the first person to need this kind of class, are there standard methods that are expected and I'm not providing?
- what's the general consensus on "operator-like" methods, such as `-` for `remove` or `+` for add?

Comment: That link for your implementation class gets  a 404.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I'd failed to pin the link to a specific git commit. It might be less than useful though, as I experimented quite a bit with this design since I initially asked the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how to understand the `KeyValueStore` without understanding the `ValueFormat` implementation you reference. You don't have **any** substantial comments in either implementation, including "why". Their mutual dependency makes it very difficult to review either of them.

Readability issues:

1. You use `ValueReader[S,T]` in the `KeyValueStore` and `ValueReader[T]` in the `ValueFormat` -- this caused many minutes of confusion and blind paths.
2. Similarly, you define `trait ValueReader[S,T]` and then you immediately turn around and use `ValueReader[T,S]` in the body of `KeyValueStore`. Swapping the parameters causes more confusion.